# is there any way to create spaces in opensearch

Tags: kibana, opensearch, opensearch-dashboards

I am using the [OpenSearch](https://opensearch.org/) tool.

is there any way to create a space for one user?

in **[Kibana](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/master/spaces-api-post.html)** I am using this API :

```
curl -X POST "https://xxxxxxx.dev/api/spaces/space" -H 'kbn-xsrf: true' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "id": "marketing",
  "name": "Marketing",
  "description" : "This is the Marketing Space",
  "color": "#aabbcc",
  "initials": "MK",
  "disabledFeatures": [],
  "imageUrl": ""
}
```

But in OpenSearch, I didn't find any document and I get this error :

```
{"statusCode":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"Not Found"}
```